# Uso de entidades não-mapeadas no Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Li que normalmente a pasta Entity de um bundle armazena as entidades que vão ser persistidas (no meu caso, pelo Doctrine) no banco de dados.

Mas, pela facilidade de se trabalhar com validações no formato "annotations" dentro de uma Entity, eu optei por criar entidades não-mapeadas (não persistíveis). Desse modo, posso validar uma estrutura de dados arbitrária utilizando todas as conveniências do Symfony2 no formato "annotations".

Portanto, minha pergunta é: existe alguma contra-indicação de se utilizar entidades não-mapeadas (pelo Doctrine) dentro do meu projeto?

Comment: Não conheço a fundo o Symfony 2, mas essa pergunta me parece mais relacionada ao próprio doctrine, @eminetto se puder responder essa...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Resposta

Não tem contra-indicação.

Você pode fazer como está pensando, obtendo os benefícios do componente de validação.

---

#### Reflexões

Uma "Entity" na verdade é um objeto comum. Através de metadados (por anotações ou arquivo de configuração) é que o Doctrine faz o seu trabalho - sem que a classe precise implementar (*implements*) uma interface ou estender (*extends*) uma hierarquia.

Portanto, talvez você queira colocar estas classes numa **outra** pasta dentro do Bundle, já que "Entity" está consagrada pelo uso como a pasta onde entidades a serem persistidas residem.

Em suma: a questão gira em torno do que significa "entidades"...  você fala em

> entidades não-mapeadas (não persistíveis)

...por mim, tudo bem, mas sabe-se lá se o nome "entidade" se refere *justamente* a "***um objeto que será mapeado/persistido***"? Por que simplesmente não enunciar "***instâncias*** não mapeadas" ou "***objetos*** não mapeados" ou "***classes*** não mapeadas"? É só não chamar os teus objetos de "entidades"! :-)

---

#### Conclusão

Enfim, na prática você pode colocar suas classes na pasta "Entity" e usar a palavra "entidades", não mapear, não usar Doctrine nem anotações ORM, mas usar anotações de validação e o componente de validação do Symfony 2 sem problemas. E você também pode, como foi dito, colocar essas tuas classes numa pasta que não seja a "Entity".

Comment: Dei uma pesquisada... engraçado que a documentação do Symfony e do Doctrine saem usando o termo "entity" sem definir o mesmo em momento algum. Difícil de achar algo "conceitual" sobre o termo. Achei aqui: http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/entity - o uso do termo está muito ligado a banco de dados e armazenamento no mesmo. Diz também que o significado é semelhante ao de "objeto" em programação orientada a objetos...

Comment: O componente de validação do Symfony 2 é independente não só do Doctrine e banco de dados, mas também dos Forms: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html - poŕem, em geral ele é usado de maneira integrada com Forms e/ou ORM.

Answer (score 1):

Eu não vejo porque isso poderia ser ruim, a única diferença é que estas entidades não seriam gerenciadas pelo EntityManager do Doctrine, certo? Você vai usá-las para outras funções dentro do projeto.
Ou você vai usar estas entidades de alguma forma com o Doctrine?

Comment: Não usarei essas entidades com o Doctrine, nem com nada relacionado a banco de dados. Serão usadas unicamente pra fazer [validações dos dados de um formulário](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html), daí meu receio de ficar parecendo gambiarra e não ser a forma recomendada de organizar meu projeto Symfony.
Você tem alguma outra recomendação quanto a isso? A princípio, imaginei que uma Entity do Symfony obrigatoriamente deveria representar um objeto a ser persistido no banco de dados.

Comment: Talvez vc poderia usar outro método de validação de dados, como o Zend/Validator ou o próprio componente do Symfony (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html). P.S.: Não uso o Symfony, então posso estar falando besteira ;)